# How to modify classpath and src/bin directory in wizard?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, classpath, wizard, buildpath

My task is create a wizard that sets up a fresh Eclipse Plugin Project in a certain way. I already managed to create wizard that creates an empty project without source/binary directory. So after some research I found out that I need to set those values in the .project-File which I have no clue how to modify properly. Also I would need set the classpath in the .classpath-File and modify that somehow. I couldn't find any documentation on this nor any other resources and my guess is that I don't create this files and write in the values manually via IO. So any link to a proper documentation or a short heads up on how to do this would help.

Comment: Note that the classpath goes in the `.classpath` file, **not** the `.project`

Comment: You are absolutely right I added that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The 'JDT Core' section of the 'Programmer's Guide' in the 'JDT Plug-in Developer Guide' in the Eclipse Help gives the basics of setting the class path.

Basically:

```java
IProject project = ... // get some project resource

IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);

IClasspathEntry[] newClasspath = ...;

javaProject.setRawClasspath(newClasspath, someProgressMonitor);
```

The `JavaCore` class has various methods for creating the different types of `IClasspathEntry` such as:

```java
IClasspathEntry srcEntry = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(new Path("/MyProject/src"));
```

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion. Then I found out that it was a terrible idea to create the whole plug-in project from scratch when I just can make some kind of wizard extension via the org.eclipse.pde.ui.pluginContent extension point. Still, thanks for answering!